# Should I manually upload these large files?

Tags: files

I have about 10 large zip files (20Mb) which need to be uploaded to a site once, and once only.  I then want to be able to download them from a block in a sidebar (i.e. not from the main content).

I was thinking that the easiest way to do this would be manually upload them to the site (via ftp), then hardcode links in the blocks to reference the file location.  Does this sound OK?  Does it violate any drupal rules?

The reasons I wanted to do it this way, rather than through the file UI or another module, are that I don't have to worry about the php.ini upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.  Also, I won't have to work out how to use the drupal UI to put a link in a block.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually uploading the files and hardcoding the links into a block, Shouldnt be a problem.

You Could also check this module out :) [Download File Module](http://drupal.org/project/download_file)

Comment: I agree with Vic, seems to upload the files manually would be appropriate in this situation.